# Changing all markers icons except for the one clicked on in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I need to set up a map with several markers.

I know it is possible to change the icon marker on click, and to change the icon marker on click on an external link. I would like to know if it is possible with the Google Maps API do to the following :

- On clic on a marker, changing the icons of **all other markers** (in order to have the marker I clicked on be on highlight and the others fade) ?
- On clic on an element, change the icon of **all other markers** (for exemple, clicking on "show event" would put the corresponding marker on highlight and the others would fade) ?

Thank you !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Google Maps marker icon when clicking on other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754101/change-google-maps-marker-icon-when-clicking-on-other)

Answer (score 1):

You need the collection of all the markers in an arrays ..

```
 var  myMarkers[]
```

Then preserve the marker you click doing a copy so you can  iterate over this array of markers and change the icon for all the markers

```
  myMarker[i].setIcon('my_new_icon.png');
```

and last preserve le marker icon

```
  myCopiedMarker.setIcon(my_old_icon.png');
```