# Save Clicked Google Maps Marker ID – Reset Icon On Next Marker Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to save a reference to a clicked Google Maps marker. Currently my code works like so:

1. Click marker.
2. Check which iconType (`data-icon-type`) the marker has (either Landmarks or Projects).
3. Depending on which iconType (`data-icon-type`) the marker has, switch the icon to the 'active' marker icon.

Steps 1 – 3 work fine. But the following is what I am currently stuck on is as follows:

4. Save out the id of the clicked marker (`data-marker-id`).
5. When clicking a new marker, get the id of the previously clicked marker, check which iconType (`data-icon-type`) the marker has (either Landmarks or Projects).
6. Reset the previously clicked marker's icon to the 'inactive' marker icon.
7. Set the newly clicked markers icon to it's 'active' icon.

I should point out that I am using the Advanced Custom Fields Google Map field to populate my map locations.

Here are the various functions for rendering the map:

```
/*
 *  new_map
 *
 *  This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
 *
 *  @type    function
 *  @date    8/11/2013
 *  @since   4.3.0
 *
 *  @param   jQueryel (jQuery element)
 *  @return  n/a
 */

function new_map(jQueryel) {

    // var
    var jQuerymarkers = jQueryel.find('.marker');

    // vars
    var args = {
        minZoom: 12,
        maxZoom: 17,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
        },
    };

    // create map               
    var map = new google.maps.Map(jQueryel[0], args);
    // add a markers reference
    map.markers = [];
    // add markers
    jQuerymarkers.each(function() {
        add_marker(jQuery(this), map);
    });
    // center map
    center_map(map);
    // return
    return map;
}




/*
     *  add_marker
     *
     *  This function will add a marker to the selected Google Map
     *
     *  @type    function
     *  @date    8/11/2013
     *  @since   4.3.0
     *
     *  @param   jQuerymarker (jQuery element)
     *  @param   map (Google Map object)
     *  @return  n/a
     */

    function add_marker(jQuerymarker, map) {

        // var
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(jQuerymarker.attr('data-lat'), jQuerymarker.attr('data-lng'));
        var markerID = jQuerymarker.attr('data-marker-id');
        var cleanTitle = jQuerymarker.attr('data-clean-title');
        var iconType = jQuerymarker.attr('data-icon-type');

        var icon = {
            url: jQuerymarker.attr('data-icon'), // url
        };

        // create marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            id: markerID,
            icon: icon
        });

        // add to array
        map.markers.push(marker);


        // show info window when marker is clicked
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            var identification;

            if (jQuery('#box').hasClass('slide-right-active')) {

                // Check to see what the previous icon was, 
                //then it swaps out the icon for the original icon

                if (prevIconType == 'landmarks') {
                    console.log("second landmarks");
                    icon = {
                        url: 'Landmarks.png', // url
                    };
                    marker.setIcon(icon);
                } else if (prevIconType == 'projects') {
                    console.log("second projects");
                    icon = {
                        url: 'Projects.png', // url
                    };
                    marker.setIcon(icon);
                }

                // Check to see what the icon the clicked marker has, 
               // then it swaps out the icon for the active icon
                if (iconType === 'landmarks') {
                    icon = {
                        url: 'Landmarks-Active.png', // url
                    };
                    marker.setIcon(icon);
                    prevIconType = 'landmarks';
                } else if (iconType === 'projects') {
                    icon = {
                        url: 'Projects-Active.png', // url
                    };
                    marker.setIcon(icon);
                    prevIconType = 'projects';
                }

            } else {

                // Check to see what the icon the clicked marker has, 
               // then it swaps out the icon for the active icon
                if (iconType === 'landmarks') {
                    icon = {
                        url: 'Landmarks-Active.png', // url
                    };
                    marker.setIcon(icon);
                    prevIconType = 'landmarks';
                } else if (iconType === 'projects') {
                    icon = {
                        url: 'Projects-Active.png', // url
                    };
                    marker.setIcon(icon);
                    prevIconType = 'projects';
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while but I figured it out looking through various other examples. The one that worked for me was: [Change Google Maps marker icon when clicking on other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754101/change-google-maps-marker-icon-when-clicking-on-other)

Here's my code for swapping out the markers on a click event.

```
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i, center) {
           var identification;
           jQueryMarkerToolTip.hide();

           return function() {
               for (var j = 0; j < markers.length; j++) {
                   if (markers[j].iconType === 'landmarks') {
                       icon = {
                           url: 'Landmarks.png', // url
                           scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30), // scaled size
                           origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
                           anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
                       };
                       markers[j].setIcon(icon);
                   }
                   if (markers[j].iconType === 'projects') {
                       icon = {
                           url: 'Projects.png', // url
                           scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30), // scaled size
                           origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
                           anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
                       };
                       markers[j].setIcon(icon);
                   }
               }
               if (iconType === 'landmarks') {
                   icon = {
                       url: 'Landmarks-Active.png', // url
                       scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30), // scaled size
                       origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
                       anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
                   };
                   marker.setIcon(icon);
               } else if (iconType === 'projects') {
                   icon = {
                       url: 'Projects-Active.png', // url
                       scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30), // scaled size
                       origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
                       anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
                   };
                   marker.setIcon(icon);
               }
           };
       })(marker, i, center));
       // add to array
       markers.push(marker);
       }
       }
```