# Multiple Map Markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to set a different marker icon size on click. The trouble I'm having is all icons with an infowindow change to the first icon item in the array. The Infowindow and data within is correct.

I've been scratching my head on this one, any ideas why the vars would be different on click? They are set using the same file path, just using different scaled sizes.

Is there a better approach to how this is currently being done?

```
var markers = new Array();
var mapMultiple;

function initMap() {

  // Get focus point
  var mapLat = parseFloat(mapVar.lat);
  var mapLng = parseFloat(mapVar.lng);
  var myLatLng = {lat: mapLat, lng: mapLng};
  

  // Get locations
  var locationsMultipleMarkers = mapVar.locationsMultipleMarkers;


  // Map Defaults
  var mapMultiple = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-multiple'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });


  // Markers and info popup
  var markerMultipleMarkers, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locationsMultipleMarkers.length; i++) {  

    var iconMultiple = locationsMultipleMarkers[i]['icon']; 

    if(!iconMultiple) {
      iconMultiple = mapVar.path + '/assets/svg/marker-default.svg';
    }

    // Icon ready state
    var iconMultipleMarkers = {
        url: iconMultiple,
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(60, 60)
    };

    // Icon active state
    var iconMultipleMarkersActive = {
        url: iconMultiple,
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(120, 120)
    };

    // Markers and info popup
    var infowindowMultipleMarkers = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var markerMultipleMarkers, i;

    markerMultipleMarkers = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locationsMultipleMarkers[i]['lat'], locationsMultipleMarkers[i]['lng']),
      map: mapMultiple,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      icon: iconMultipleMarkers
    });

    markers.push(markerMultipleMarkers);

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerMultipleMarkers, 'click', (function(markerMultipleMarkers, i) {

      return function() {
        if(locationsMultipleMarkers[i]['marker_info']) {
          for (var j = 0; j < markers.length; j++) {
            markers[j].setIcon(iconMultipleMarkers);
          }
          this.setIcon(iconMultipleMarkersActive);
          infowindowMultipleMarkers.setContent(locationsMultipleMarkers[i]['marker_info']);
          infowindowMultipleMarkers.open(mapMultiple, markerMultipleMarkers);
        }
      }
    })(markerMultipleMarkers, i));

  }
 
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  Possible duplicate of [Change Google Maps marker icon when clicking on other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754101/change-google-maps-marker-icon-when-clicking-on-other)

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your code, with some ( ok, lots of ) modifications and a degree of creative license, I put together a demo of how you can essentially toggle each marker you have loaded onto the map between two states - differing here simply by the `scaledSize` property only as far as I can tell from your code. Personally I found it a little confusing when there were several variables with similar long names - just sort of adds too much clutter to my mind.

Assuming that the source data is probably being derived from a database query and output as JSON I generated some dummy data based upon the various properties of the `mapVar` variable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google Maps: </title>
        <style>
            #map{
                width:800px;
                height:600px;
                float:none;
                margin:auto;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
        
            const mapVar={
                path:'/path/to/images/markers',
                sizes:{         //  sizes used to build `Icons`
                    ready:32,   //  default ->  60
                    active:60   //  default ->  120
                },
                lat:56.522556,  //  default latitude ~ details unknown
                lng:-2.969856,  //  default longitude ~ details unknown
                locations:[     //  example data
                    {
                        "name": "Glaxo - 2 x 132m turbines",
                        "lat": "56.70431711148748",
                        "lng": "-2.4660869436035",
                        "marker_info": "Glaxo - 2 x 132m turbines, 2 Blade Turbine, 5 Meridian St, Montrose, Angus DD10 8DS, UK",
                        "icon": "/images/css/2_blade_turbine.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Carsegownie - 1 x78m turbine",
                        "lat": "56.67951330362271",
                        "lng": "-2.8062983350524746",
                        "marker_info": "Carsegownie - 1 x78m turbine, Anemometer, B9134, Forfar, Angus DD8, UK",
                        "icon": "/images/css/mappoint-anemometer.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Frawney - Over Finlarg - 5x100m turbines",
                        "lat": "56.56806620951482",
                        "lng": "-2.9501720266113125",
                        "marker_info": "Frawney - Over Finlarg - 5x100m turbines, Antenna, Kerton Farm, Forfar, Angus DD8, UK",
                        "icon": "/images/css/mappoint-antenna.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Dodd Hill - 5 x 125m turbines",
                        "lat": "56.54251020079966",
                        "lng": "-2.9051538305053555",
                        "marker_info": "Dodd Hill - 5 x 125m turbines, Simple, 4 Backmuir Rd, Duntrune, Tealing, Dundee, Angus DD4 0PT, UK.",
                        "icon": "/images/css/mappoint-blue.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Ark Hill - 8 x 81m turbines",
                        "lat": "56.57065514278748",
                        "lng": "-3.0511732892761074",
                        "marker_info": "Ark Hill - 8 x 81m turbines, New location, 3 Dryburn Cottages, Glenogilvy, Forfar, Angus DD8 1UP, UK",
                        "icon": "/images/css/mappoint-green.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Nathro 17 x 135m turbines",
                        "lat": "56.793249595719956",
                        "lng": "-2.8623101711273193",
                        "marker_info": "Nathro 17 x 135m turbines, House, 1 Goynd Steading, Glenogil, Forfar, Angus DD8 3SW, UK.",
                        "icon": "/images/css/mappoint_house.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Govals - 6 x 87m turbines",
                        "lat": "56.582320876071854",
                        "lng": "-2.9509015874633633",
                        "marker_info": "Govals - 6 x 87m turbines, McDonalds, B9127, Forfar, Angus DD8, UK.",
                        "icon": "/images/css/mappoint_mcdonalds.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "The Carrach - 9 x 84m turbines",
                        "lat": "56.6938437674986",
                        "lng": "-3.131382067657455",
                        "marker_info": "The Carrach - 9 x 84m turbines, vawt, B951, Kirriemuir, Angus DD8, UK",
                        "icon": "/images/css/vawt.png"
                    }
                ]
            };
        
            class marker{
                /*
                    simple class to add new marker and assign callbacks.
                    Override default options by giving different args at
                    runtime.
                */
                constructor( map, latlng, args={}, callbacks=false ){
                    this.map=map;
                    this.latlng=latlng;
                    this.args=args;
                    this.callbacks=callbacks;
                    return this.create();
                };
                create(){
                    let options=Object.assign({
                        clickable:true,
                        draggable:false,
                        position:this.latlng,
                        map:this.map
                    },this.args );
                    
                    let mkr=new google.maps.Marker( options );
                    if( this.callbacks && Object.keys( this.callbacks ).length > 0 ){
                        Object.keys( this.callbacks ).forEach( event => {
                            google.maps.event.addListener( mkr, event, this.callbacks[ event ] );
                        })
                    }
                    return mkr;
                };
            };
        
        
            function initMap(){
                let markers=[];
                let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( mapVar.lat, mapVar.lng );
                let locations=mapVar.locations;
                
                let map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 9,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });
                
                locations.forEach( obj=>{
                    let icon=obj.icon || mapVar.path + '/assets/svg/marker-default.svg';
                    
                    // A default Icon to be used when creating the map
                    let _default={
                        url:icon,
                        scaledSize:new google.maps.Size( mapVar.sizes.ready, mapVar.sizes.ready )
                    };
                    // The alternative state Icon to be displayed when marker is clicked.
                    let _active={
                        url:icon,
                        scaledSize:new google.maps.Size( mapVar.sizes.active, mapVar.sizes.active )
                    };
                    /*
                        custom properties to assign to the marker using the marker class above.
                        
                        The `content` is used to build the infowindow - from mapVar data.
                        The `index` is used to determine which marker to select from the array.
                        The `infowindow` becomes a property of the marker... many markers might cause issues!
                    */
                    let args={
                        index:0,
                        infowindow:new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
                        content:obj.marker_info,
                        icon:_default
                    };
                    
                    // toggle between these Icons
                    let Icons=[ _default, _active ];
                    
                    // assign whatever callbacks are needed to be used with the new marker.
                    let callbacks={
                        click:function(e){
                            this.index = 1 - this.index;
                            this.setIcon( Icons[ this.index ] );
                            
                            // open the infowindow
                            with( this.infowindow ){
                                setContent( this.content );
                                setPosition( e.latLng );
                                open( map, this );
                            }
                            
                            // if the infowindow is open, close it
                            if( !this.index )this.infowindow.close()
                        }
                    };
                    
                    markers.push( new marker( map, new google.maps.LatLng( obj.lat, obj.lng ), args, callbacks ) );
                });
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<APIKEY>&callback=initMap'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The icons could be completely different rather than just a different size if needed.

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/RamRaider/y28n37pu/4/)